# Ubuntu 20.04 application menu problem when group application

Tags: gnome-shell, 20.04, appmenu

When I group LibreOffice applications, it creates many point entry, you can see this on the right of the screen I have 10 points whereas I just have the common applications.

[image: Applications menu]

Do you have any idea how to fix this problem ?